# Does centripetal force constitute a torque?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, angular-momentum, torque, centripetal-force

I was going through Kepler's laws when I stumbled upon this concept. The angular momentum of a revolving body(say, electron) is conserved as torque about the centre(nucleus) is zero. How is the torque zero?

Comment: Both the speed (velocity) and radius change unless its a circular orbit (here its pretty much obvious that there is no torque).

Comment: Oh thanx. I got confused with torque as force X distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Torque is the cross product of the force and radius vectors. In the case of a centripetal force the angle between these two vectors is 180 degrees and so the cross product is zero. It's like applying a force on a door directly towards these hinges - it won't produce any rotation.